# how to open only one collapse button inside for loop in django

Tags: django, bootstrap-5

I am working on a practice project for a weather app, showing the next 7 days of weather forecast when clicking the button in a current weather `bootstrap5 card`.
Using bootstrap collapse shows every city's daily weather forecasts at once. which part should I change and I haven't learned javascript yet.

The next 7days of the weather forecast list(`city_weather_forecast`) is placed in the current city weather status(`city_weather_data`) so that the current city's latitude and longitude can be used to get info for a daily forecast.

#### views.py/ parts for the context to provide templates.

```
def index(request):
    current_weather_url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={}&units=metric&appid={}"
    forcast_weather_url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat={}&lon={}&units=metric&exclude=current,minutely,hourly&appid={}"
    api_key = "3305a1cea0761d956da3c5f87c21b563"

    message = ''
    err_msg = ''
    message_class = ''

    form = CityForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CityForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_city = form.cleaned_data['name']
            count_city_in_data = City.objects.filter(name=new_city).count()
            if count_city_in_data == 0:
                r = requests.get(current_weather_url.format(new_city, api_key)).json()
                if r["cod"] == 200:
                    form.save()
                    return redirect('weather:home')
                else:
                    err_msg = "The city name is not a proper name."
            else:
                err_msg = "The city is already in your list."
    
    if err_msg:
        message = err_msg
        message_class = 'alert-danger'
    else:
        message = 'The city is added successfully.'
        message_class = 'alert-success'
    
    cities = City.objects.all().order_by('-created_date')
    weather_data = []
    
    for city in cities:
        # Current weather status
        current_r = requests.get(current_weather_url.format(city, api_key)).json()
        
        # print("current_r : ", current_r["dt"])
        # print(forcast_r["daily"][1]["dt"])
        # print(len(forecast_r["daily"]))  including today, total 8 days of weather forecasts.
        
        
        # Forecast next 7 days.
        city_weather_forecast = []
        forecast_r = requests.get(forcast_weather_url.format(current_r["coord"]["lat"], current_r["coord"]["lon"], api_key)).json()
        daily_weather_7days = forecast_r["daily"][1:] # excluding today.
        
        for daily_weather in daily_weather_7days:
            # Convert Timestapt to human readable time.
            date = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(daily_weather["dt"]).strftime("%m/%d")
            day = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(daily_weather["dt"]).strftime("%A")
            city_weather_forcast_data = {
                'date': date,
                'day': day,
                'icon': daily_weather["weather"][0]["icon"],
                'min': daily_weather["temp"]["min"],
                'max': daily_weather["temp"]["max"],
            }

            city_weather_forecast.append(city_weather_forcast_data)
        
        # Include daily forecasts and current weather status and give this info to templates.
        city_weather_data = {
            'city': city.name,
            'country': current_r["sys"]["country"],
            'description': current_r["weather"][0]["description"],
            'icon': current_r["weather"][0]["icon"],
            'temp': current_r["main"]["temp"],
            'lat': current_r["coord"]["lat"],
            'lon': current_r["coord"]["lon"],
            'forecasts': city_weather_forecast,         
        }
        
        weather_data.append(city_weather_data)
    

    context = {
        'weather_data': weather_data,
        'form': form,
        'message': message,
        'message_class': message_class,
        }
    return render(request, 'weather/index.html', context)
```

#### templates

```
{% if weather_data %}
<div class="delete-all">
    <div class="delete-all-button">
        <a href="{% url 'weather:delete_all_city' %}"><button class="btn btn-danger"><i class="delete-element glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Delete All</button></a>
    </div>
</div>
{% for city in weather_data %}
<div class="container-weather-card">
    <div class="card card-bg">
        <div class="card-body">
            <img class="card-img" src="http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/{{ city.icon }}.png" alt="image">
            <h2 class="card-title">{{city.city}}, <span class="card-subtitle">{{ city.country }}</span></h2>
            <h4 class="card-temp">{{ city.temp }} °C</h4>
            <p class="card-text">{{ city.description }}</p>
            <button class="btn btn-position btn-outline-danger"><i class="delete-element glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i><a class="delete-element" href="{% url 'weather:delete_city' city.city %}"> Delete</a></button>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-forecast" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#weather-7days" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="weather-7days"><span>Next 7days</span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% for city_forecast in city.forecasts %}
<div class="collapse" id="weather-7days">
    <div class="container-weather-forecast card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md card-section">
                    <p>{{ city_forecast.date }}</p>
                    <p>{{ city_forecast.day}}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md">
                    <img class="forcast-img" src="http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/{{ city_forecast.icon }}.png" alt="image">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md card-section">
                    <p>Low  {{ city_forecast.min }} °C</p>
                    <p>High {{ city_forecast.max }} °C</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: What are you saying, you have an expand/collapse (accordion) block of various items which you only want to have 1 open at a time. So clicking a closed one would open it & close the open one?

Comment: If you are grabing weather reports from openweathermap api then I suggest you to use openweatherpy module - https://pypi.org/project/openweatherpy/

Comment: @markwalker_ yes when I click the button("next 7days"), I want the other open "7days forecast" closed and want to have the collapse not opening the block downwards as usual, but left or right side. because I put those weather status in the middle of the web page with width 30%.